# How to reduce Header at the top of the page

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-eleven

Using  a new theme and wondered how I go about reducing the black space above the header as currently it is too deep.

The site in question is here
http://www.marqueehireauckland.net.nz/

The theme is twenty eleven

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

no coding needed - in the dashboard under ***Appearance -> Header*** - ***Display Text: No***
this also cleanly moves the searchbox into the menu line.

edit: a css possibility would be to reduce the top padding in the style of `#site-title`.

Answer (score 0):

That black space is where the name of the website is normally displayed. If you're not going to show the title there, you can remove that space by adding the following CSS to the bottom of `style.css`:

```
#site-title { display: none; }
#branding #searchform { top: 0; }
```

Want to tighten it up even more? Try this:

```
#site-title, #site-description { display: none; }
#branding #searchform { top: 294px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your theme folder (/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven) and on header.php remove everything between the following:

```
<hgroup> ... </hgroup>
```

Comment: That does the same thing as my answer, but you'll end up with the search form on top of the image, which you may not want. You'll still have to edit the style.css to move the search form where you want.

Comment: I agree that more CSS tuning may need to be done, but in general you should not leave elements on the page that are simply hidden by CSS.